# Pass a javascript function through JQuery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically what I am trying to do is pass a callback function through PHP using JQuery `$.post`. Something like:

```
function loadPage()
{
    $.post('myurl.php', { 'callbackfunc' : function (info) { alert(info); } }, 
        function(data) {
            $("#divid").html(data);
     } );
}
```

Where `myurl.php` creates a page with a table. The table rows have an `onclick` handler that calls the callback function.

The problem is, passing the function this way sends it as `undefined` via post, and if I enclose it in quotes, then when I try to call it I get the error that it is not a function.

Is there any way to do what I am describing?

Comment: may i ask what you plan to do with this function in php?

Comment: The AJAX post creates a table with information from the database in it. When the user clicks on a row in the table, the callback function gets called. This allows the table to be portable and have the onclick be different every where that it is used.

Answer (score 1):

there is a way but not normally recommended. You can pass the function as a string and then when you receive the function with javascript use the eval() function.

```
function loadPage()
{
    $.post('myurl.php', { 'callbackfunc' : "function (info) { alert(info); }" }, 
        function(data) {
            $("#divid").html(eval(data));
     } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**pass it as a string** (function body in double quotes, probably using escape characters).

Comment: function is a normal javascript variable. It is not called here.

Comment: still the following needs to be done:   { 'callbackfunc' : "function (info) { alert(info); }" }

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do what you are describing, but there is a probably way to do what you want. ( i dont know what you want )

you cant pass a JS function to the server. you can only pass strings.

**edit**:
based on your response, i can tell you that your way of doing this is not only not good, but dangerous, as it allows XSS.

it would be better to delegate the click function to the div where you are inserting the table like this:

```
function loadPage(){
    $("#divid").delegate('tr', 'click', function(evt){
      //this code is different per page, change color, alert, etc
    });
    //after the above event is delegated, you can reload the table as much as you want, without needing to rebind the above event
    $.post('myurl.php', function(data) {
        $("#divid").html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: The best way I can think of how to explain it is, I have three pages that all need the same table, so all three pages call the same $.post to AJAXically load the table. Each page, however, does something different when the user clicks on a row in the table. For page 1, I want to alert the row id, for page 2, I want to change the color, and for page 3, I want to do a redirect. Thus I want to pass a different callback function from each page that will be called through the tr's onclick handler

Answer (score 0):

You could attach your function to your table rows after the table has been returned, rather than try to have the php code create it with the proper callback.

```
function loadPage(callbackfunc)
{
    $.post('myurl.php', {}, 
        function(data) {
            $("#divid").html(data);
            $("#divid").find("tr").each($(this).click(callbackfunc));
    } );
}
```